# Replace first number of a phone number mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database table `users` that has a column called `mobile`. All the mobile phone numbers start with `0` e.g.: `0455000000`

I want to replace ONLY the very first number which is a always a `0` with `61`

That would turn the mobile number from `0455000000` to `61455000000`

I'm guessing using a trim statement may work but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: replace it with what?

Comment: Sorry. have updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a convenient function called `insert()`.  This lets you replace a substring by position.

So:

```
select insert(phone, 1, 1, '')          -- gets rid of the first digit
select insert(phone, 1, 1, 'Mobile #')  -- replaces the first digit with a different prefix
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `substring` to remove first character from your mobile and then `concat` a value at the beginning which you want to replace it with:

```
UPDATE users
SET mobile = concat('61', substring(mobile, 2))
```

This is ANSI-SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first 0, prepend with 61... and insert it to dB, do this:

```
INSERT into phone_numbers(id, number) VALUE (null, CONCAT('61', SUBSTR('0455000000', 2)))
```

Basically it uses SUBSTR http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
set @phone  = '0455000000';
select CONCAT_WS("",'61',SUBSTR(@phone FROM 2));
```